# Two data sets with diferent Y axis plus axis title

Tags: angular, charts, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have been trying to create, using nativescript+angular (native UI chart), a chart that uses two different sets of data. One for temperature and another for pressure, each with their own Y axis (one right and one left)
I have managed to do it either using bar for the pressure and line for the temperature or by overlaping two charts.

Is it not currently possible to display two sets of data using the same kind of graph (linear in my case) ?. 
Also, is it possible to provide a title to the axis (Eg: C°, bar, sec) ?

Here are my attempts

Overlaping:

```
<GridLayout rows="*">

<StackLayout row="0">
<StackLayout backgroundColor="rgb(66, 66, 66)">
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" width="96%" height="100%">
    <DockLayout height="100%" width="100%">
        <RadCartesianChart class="cartesianChart0" backgroundColor="rgb(66, 66, 66)" >

        <BarSeries tkCartesianSeries stackMode="Stack" seriesName="Total">
            <LinearAxis tkBarVerticalAxis lineHidden="True" horizontalLocation="Right" 
            labelMargin="10"></LinearAxis>
        </BarSeries>    
        <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis ></CategoricalAxis>

        <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis horizontalLocation="Left" labelMargin="10" ></LinearAxis>

        <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries stackMode="Stack" legendTitle="Fahrenheit" showLabels="true" 
        labelFormat="degrees" seriesName="Fahrenheit" [items]="fahrenheit" categoryProperty="time" 
        valueProperty="degrees"> </LineSeries>

        <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries stackMode="Stack" legendTitle="Celsius" showLabels="true" 
        seriesName="celsius" [items]="celsius" categoryProperty="time" valueProperty="degrees">
        </LineSeries>

        </RadCartesianChart>
    </DockLayout>
</StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout row="0">
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" width="100%" height="100%">
    <DockLayout height="100%" width="100%">
        <RadCartesianChart class="cartesianChart0">

        <BarSeries tkCartesianSeries stackMode="Stack" seriesName="Total">
            <LinearAxis tkBarVerticalAxis lineHidden="True" horizontalLocation="Left" labelMargin="10"></LinearAxis>
        </BarSeries>    
        <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis hidden="True"></CategoricalAxis>

        <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis horizontalLocation="Right" labelMargin="10" ></LinearAxis>

        <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries stackMode="Stack" legendTitle="Bars" showLabels="true" seriesName="bars" 
            [items]="pressure" categoryProperty="time" valueProperty="bars" lineColor= "blue">
        </LineSeries>
        </RadCartesianChart>
    </DockLayout>
</StackLayout>
</StackLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

Line and bar:

```
<StackLayout backgroundColor="rgb(66, 66, 66)">
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" width="100%" height="100%">
        <DockLayout height="100%" width="100%">
            <RadCartesianChart class="cartesianChart0" backgroundColor="rgb(66, 66, 66)" >
                <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis labelMargin="10"></CategoricalAxis>

                <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis horizontalLocation="Left" ></LinearAxis>

                <RadLegendView tkCartesianLegend position="Top" title="Celsius, fahrenheit, bars vs seconds" 
                height="150" enableSelection="true"></RadLegendView>

                <BarSeries tkCartesianSeries stackMode="Stack" seriesName="Total" [items]="pressure"
                    categoryProperty="time" valueProperty="bars">
                        <LinearAxis tkBarVerticalAxis horizontalLocation="Right" ></LinearAxis>
                </BarSeries>

                <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries stackMode="Stack" legendTitle="Fahrenheit" showLabels="true" labelFormat="degrees" seriesName="Fahrenheit" 
                [items]="fahrenheit" categoryProperty="time" valueProperty="degrees">
                </LineSeries>

                <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries stackMode="Stack" legendTitle="Celsius" showLabels="true" seriesName="celsius" 
                [items]="celsius" categoryProperty="time" valueProperty="degrees">
                </LineSeries>

            </RadCartesianChart>
        </DockLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to solve it thanks to the help of the developers. The vertical linear axes had to be included inside their corresponding line series. Something that I tried myself but for a reason I cannot explain, it did not work for me before.

Still, if someone knows how to show the unit above each axis that would be really helpful.

Here is the solution code:

html:

```
<ActionBar title="nativescript-ui-chart" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>

<GridLayout>
    <ScrollView class="page">
        <StackLayout class="home-panel">
            <GridLayout rows="*" height="1000px">
                <RadCartesianChart row="0">
                    <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis
                        verticalLocation="Down"></CategoricalAxis>

                    <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries seriesName="RateA" [items]="categoricalSource" showLabels="true"
                        categoryProperty="time" valueProperty="celsius">
                        <LinearAxis tkLineVerticalAxis horizontalLocation="Left"></LinearAxis>
                    </LineSeries>

                    <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries seriesName="Total" [items]="categoricalSource" showLabels="true"
                        categoryProperty="time" valueProperty="pressure">
                        <LinearAxis tkLineVerticalAxis horizontalLocation="Right"></LinearAxis>
                    </LineSeries>
                </RadCartesianChart>
            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-items",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./chart.component.html",
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
    categoricalSource: { time: number, celsius: number, pressure: number }[] = [
        { time: 0 , celsius: 7, pressure: 1 },
        { time: 10, celsius: 15, pressure: 2 },
        { time: 20, celsius: 18, pressure: 5 },
        { time: 30, celsius: 20, pressure: 7 },
        { time: 40, celsius: 30, pressure: 10 }
    ];


    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```